# Как отследить ошибку в реальном времени в unpit

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Есть  `input[login]` , и он должен быть уникальным. Требуется перехватить написание, и когда login уже будет написан, он должен писать что такой логин уже есть до того как пользователь нажмет кнопку регистрация.
Как это можно сделать средствами Flask/Jinja?

Comment: Ни flask, ни jinja, ни вместе не помогут этого добиться - это серверные штуки. Нужны клиентские технологии. Надо учить [JavaScript](https://learn.javascript.ru/) и AJAX.